# Почему std::pair имеет пользовательский оператор присваивания, а не использует default версию?

Tags: c++, оператор-присваивания

Почему `std::pair` имеет пользовательский оператор присваивания, а не использует `default` версию?

Код из `libc++` просто делает почленное присваивание, что и сделал бы дефолтный оператор:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
pair& operator=(typename conditional<
                    is_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                    is_copy_assignable<second_type>::value,
                pair, __nat>::type const& __p)
    _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
               is_nothrow_copy_assignable<second_type>::value)
{
    first = __p.first;
    second = __p.second;
    return *this;
}
```

Копирующий конструктор, например, использует дефолтную реализацию, так что это не code style:

```
pair(pair const&) = default;
```

Comment: В стандарте именно так описан шаблон pair: https://eel.is/c++draft/pairs#pair

Comment: @Croessmah ну вот `constexpr pair& operator=(const pair& p);` видите, почему он не `default`, а `pair(const pair&) = default;` в то же время?

Comment: добавил ответ. В следующий раз, пожалуйста, перед публикацией вопроса, проверяйте его правильность, чтобы отвечающим не приходилось отвечать по нескольку раз на разные вопросы.

Comment: @Croessmah сам вопрос не изменялся, просто не тот пример скопировал

Comment: при этом изменилась вся суть происходящего, т.к. то был совершенно другой оператор и совершенно другая причина его введения. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В стандарте языка этот оператор объявлен именно явно. Если посмотреть примечание к данному оператору, то там сказано

> Remarks: This operator is defined as deleted unless `is_­copy_­assignable_­v<first_­type>` is `true` and `is_­copy_­assignable_­v<second_­type>` is `true`.

То есть аргументы шаблона должны удовлетворять требованиям `std::is_­copy_­assignable`.
`std::is_­copy_­assignable` требует, чтобы первый аргумент мог присваиваться из константного второго: `std::is_assignable<T&, const T&>`.

В свою очередь, `std::is_assignable` должен давать `true`, если выражение `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` является компилируемым, т.е. объекту типа `T` можно присвоить объект типа `U`.

Т.е. следующий код не должен компилироваться:

```
std::pair<int[4], int> p1;
std::pair<int[4], int> p2;
p2 = p1;//Должна быть ошибка
```

Так вот, если оставить оператор по-умолчанию, то ошибки не будет. Давайте сделаем имитацию на собственном классе:

```
template<typename T>
struct tester
{    
    tester& operator=(tester const &) = default;
    T mem;
};

tester<int[4]> p1;
tester<int[4]> p2;
p2 = p1;//Нет ошибки
using type = int[4];
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<type>, "");//Ошибка
```

Как видим, ошибка отсутствует, хотя `static_assert` показывает, что тип `int[4]` не удовлетворяет требованиям `is_copy_assignable`.

Поэтому, неявно генерируемый оператор присваивания не подходит.

Однако, уже явно написанный оператор проходит наш тест и мы получаем ошибку при присваивании массивов.

```
tester& operator=(tester const & rhv)
{
    mem = rhv.mem;
    return *this;
}
```

Дополнительно нужно "навесить" проверок времени компиляции, как и сделано в приведенном в вопросе примере.

Comment: Так зачем нам лишние ошибки? Если бы был дефолтный, то не было бы и ошибок, как вы говорите.

Comment: @foobar потому что пара хранит объекты. Логично, что пара, не должна менять семантику хранящихся объектов. В случае массивов - это не так, структура, содержащая массив умеет присваиваться. Вот чтобы это семантическое правило поддерживалось, нужно изменить семантику стандартного оператора присваивания.

Comment: Что значит "не должна менять семантику хранящихся объектов" не совсем понял. Почему тогда не сделать их константными, если они не должны меняться?

Comment: @foobar если вы попробуете присвоить один массив другому - этого сделать не получится. Поэтому, пара, содержащая массивы тоже не должна уметь присваивать массивы. А константными их сделать нельзя, потому что пара должна хранить объект заданного типа, а не его константную версию, т.е. пара не навешивает никаких дополнительных квалификаторов. Массиву нельзя присвоить другой массив, но ведь объекты в массиве можно менять при этом.

Comment: Так в примере же у вас указатели хранятся, а их можно присваивать. То есть `p2 = p1;` присвоит указатель на первый элемент `p1.mem` другому указателю `p2.mem`. И это ожидаемое поведение, зачем его запрещать не понимаю

Comment: @foobar где у меня хранятся указатели? Тип `T` будет `int[4]` - массив из четырех объектов типа `int`

Comment: @foobar надеюсь, вы не отождествляете массив с указателем? Это совершенно разные типы.

Comment: Почему тогда дефолтный оператор работает? Что он делает не так, как ваш?

Comment: @foobar потому что неявно генерируемый оператор присваивания не просто "присваивает все члены данных". У него свои правила: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#12 - "if the subobject is an array, each element is assigned, in the manner appropriate to the element type;" 
т.е. такой оператор не присваивает массивы, а присваивает элементы массива друг другу.

Comment: Ну так отлично, мы же именно этого и ожидаем в таком случае! Зачем запрещать такой оператор?

Comment: @foobar нет, мы как раз этого не ожидаем. Пара хранит объекты и должна обеспечивать семантику работы этих объектов, т.е. когда я присваиваю одну пару другой, я ожидаю, что пара будет присваивать один объект другому, и, если они не умеют присваиваться, я получу ошибку. Если же пара присваивает то, что присваиваться не должно - это плохо.

Comment: @foobar банально, если работает `p1 = p2`, то должно работать и `p1.first = p2.first`.

Comment: Ну ок, теперь похоже имеет смысл

Comment: В дополнение https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D удаление ввели только с 11 стандарта, до этого код был бы просто ill-formed

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы оператор присваивания мог работать даже с типами, инстанциированными ссылками.

https://godbolt.org/z/jq648q

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T1, class T2>
struct pair {
    T1 first;
    T2 second;

    // pair& operator=(const pair&) = default; // 1

    pair& operator=(const pair& rhs) { // 2
        first = rhs.first;
        second = rhs.second;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    pair<int&, int> p1{x, y}, p2{y, x};
    p1 = p2;
    std::cout << p1.first << p1.second << p2.first << p2.second << '\n';
}
```

Если тут закомментировать 2 и раскомментировать 1, то не будет работать, а сейчас работает.